# Why does this work with G++ and not CLANG?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, clang

Trying to learn C/C++.

Why does this work when use `g++` and not `clang`? But it works when I convert the same program to plain C and use `gcc` and `clang`...

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef ARCH
#define ARCH "Undefined"
#endif

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char str[] = "Hello C++";
  cout << "Value of str is : " << str << endl;
  cout << "Value of str is : " << ARCH << endl;
  exit(0);
}
```

Using `g++` I run `` g++ "-DARCH=\"`uname -m`\"" hello.cpp `` and it works just fine.

Using `clang` I run `` clang "-DARCH=\"`uname -m`\"" hello.cpp `` and it fails.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in hello-7c7087.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in hello-7c7087.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-7c7087.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in hello-7c7087.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in hello-7c7087.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-7c7087.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in hello-7c7087.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in hello-7c7087.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in hello-7c7087.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in hello-7c7087.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in hello-7c7087.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What really doesn't make sense to me is that it works both ways if I convert the code to C.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does it fail? Can't reproduce

Comment: It fails saying `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` followed by a bunch of wild errors. I will edit the question with the fail errors.

Comment: Seems to work fine on Clang https://godbolt.org/z/iTDpZH

Comment: This seems like it's an issue with one of the compilers not being set up properly, rather than anything specific about the code you've posted here.

Comment: Are you using `clang` or `clang++`?

Comment: This is C++ code, you need to invoke `clang++`. `clang` is by default the C frontend, so you don't get the C++ standard library linked automatically.

Comment: Note: for C++ code you should use `clang++`, not `clang`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you're using `clang` to compile the C++ code. You should be using `clang++` to compile it

Also you may want to use `-Wall` and possibly `-Werror` to catch many thing that might be an error in other languages (ex: not returning anything in a function with an int return type).

I personally compile with the below. I'm not sure if sanitize works on windows. no-exceptions and no-rtti is common but not what most people do. You'll have some errors with dynamic_cast and exceptions if you use these.

> clang++ -g -fsanitize=undefined -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra myfile.cpp